# Equivalence of java.util.ResourceBundle in C++

Tags: java, c++, equivalence

I have a Java class that uses more lines similar to the following ones

```
private static final int PARAM_1 = Integer.valueOf(ResourceBundle.getBundle("solution.filtres").getString("filtre.param1.solution"));
private static final int PARAM_2 = Integer.valueOf(ResourceBundle.getBundle("solution.filtres").getString("filtre.param2.solution"));
```

and the file `filtres.properties` found in `solution` folder contains:

```
filtre.param1.solution=1.5
filtre.param2.solution=6
```

I know that `ResourceBundle` is used for user locale, but it seems that it just assigns values to static members from a specific file.

I want to do something similar in C++. I have found [this](http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale/resources) for C++, but it seems a little strange for what it does; so I am asking:

1. Is it something similar to ResourceBundle in C++ (not what I have found)? If yes, what, and where can I find some examples?
2. Do you advice me to do it in a simpler way?

I would appreciate some code if anyone did some kind of this assignments.

Comment: Embedding data inside an executable is possible but only with OS specific APIs / toolchains. There is nothing like this in `std`

Comment: Thank you, sounds like I need to do something custom made, like a .txt from where I read, or simpler, just a class with those members

Comment: Normal files are no problem at all. You might have a look at http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Util.PropertyFileConfiguration.html which provides an interface for java like property files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Boost and its `pthree` and the .xml or .json parser is a better way.

Comment: Good catch. But `ptree` is available starting boost v. 1.41.1 and some people still have to use older version of boost.

Comment: I feel bad for them, but this was my solution... Anyway, why they are forced to have an old version?

Answer (score 0):

[ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) allows to retrieve textual data for a key, returning a result based on a specified locale. I'm not aware of an exact match for this in C++, but I would like to recommend using [GNU gettext()](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) as an option for implementing a similar type of internationalization support.